# Is there a way to display .eps (vector) files in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, eps

I'm new to RoR and can't seem find anything that simply explains what file types are supported.  I'm assuming .eps is not because it simply won't work in my app (other file types do such as .png so I know it's not some other problem), so curious if there is a workaround to get .eps images to show in a RoR app?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some digging.  .svg files work in Rails and they are vector images.  I used an online file converter like this one to convert .eps files.

http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg

Answer (score 1):

Googled around and found this old project:

https://github.com/Bluejade/PrawnVectorImport

No activity for a while. They might just be done?